# SQL previous next row

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

i have a table 1 with all record :

```
Id, Arrival,Departure, Datestamp (Datestamp is unique)
1 LG LE 2011-11-12 12:30:57
2 LE LG 2010-11-12 12:30:51
3 LE LG 2019-10-12 12:30:36
4 LG LE 2009-09-12 12:20:45
5 LP LA 2008-11-12 11:30:25
6 LP LA 2007-07-12 12:40:56
7 LA LP 2005-03-12 12:55:51
8 LG LP 2001-11-12 12:22:25
```

i want select all record whith Départure from row = Arrival from prévious row order by datestamp DESC

Example :

```
1 LG LE 2011-11-12 12:30:57
3 LE LG 2019-10-12 12:30:36
4 LG LE 2009-09-12 12:20:45
6 LP LA 2007-07-12 12:40:56
7 LA LP 2005-03-12 12:55:51
```

Comment: No id column or similar?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no previous or next row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Depending on what database you're using, you may be able to use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) to accomplish what you want. take a look at `row_number`, `lag` and `lead`.

Comment: ersion PHP 5.2.17, Mysql : 5.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997714/mysql-order-row-on-previous-column-value-compare-order-by-date

Answer (score 1):

select a.Arrival,a.Departure, a.Date from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.Arrival=b.OArrival and a.Departure1=ODeparture1

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997714/mysql-order-row-on-previous-column-value-compare-order-by-date